# Define Read-Only Abstract Properties in PHP

Tags: php

I want to do something like the following for an abstract class in PHP:

```
abstract class SimpleAbstractObject {
    // Not valid PHP code
    abstract protected static $Description;

    public static function getDescription(){
        return self::$Description;
    }
}
```

Naturally, the above fails to run:

```
Fatal error: Properties cannot be declared abstract
```

The idea is that any class extending the 'SimpleAbstractObject' has to define the "Description" variable and it can not be changed after it's defined.  For example:

```
class SimpleObject extends SimpleAbstractObject {
    protected static $Description = "This is a Simple Object";
}
class AnotherObject extends SimpleAbstractObject {
    protected static $Description = "This is a Another more complicated object";
}
```

So that the end result is used something like this:

```
echo SimpleObject::getDescription();
echo AnotherObject::getDescription();
```

The above would print out:

```
This is a Simple Object
This is a Another more complicated object
```

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't be using a `static` member here. The description belongs to the instance, surely, so it should not be static.

Comment: You're doing it wrong, to learn why, have a look at: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-single-responsibility-principle/

Comment: @bad_boy thank you for the article.  I completely agree with it's argument.  After giving it some thought I am still struggling to find the connection to my example.  Could you perhaps offer me a hint?  Assuming of course that I provide a more complete version of it: http://pastebin.com/TG5GEyy5

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1Ceyr8cM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `static` keyword for its [late-static-binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) properties since 5.3.

```
abstract class SimpleAbstractObject {
    public static function getDescription() {
        if(!isset(static::$Description))
            throw new UnexpectedValueException(
              get_called_class() .
              ' must define a static getDescription method');
        return static::$Description;
    }
}
```

The subclasses remain as you have them

```
class SimpleObject extends SimpleAbstractObject {
    protected static $Description = "This is a Simple Object";
}
class AnotherObject extends SimpleAbstractObject {
    protected static $Description = "This is a Another more complicated object";
}
```

but now work as expected

> This is a Simple Object This is a Another more complicated object

The only disadvantage of this approach is you loose the *'compile time'* check.

Comment: Excellent! Except for the compile time check this may be enough.